# divs height and width are not fixed in carousel slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Visit this link for code snippet https://codepen.io/arunkayathi/pen/dRPYzz

html

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700,700i|Merriweather:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
    <link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
    <section id="projects">
        <div class="content-box">
            <div class="content-title wow animated fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                <h3>My Projects</h3>
                <div class="content-title-underline"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="my-projects" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                            <div class="project-list">
                                <div class="project-image">
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTp1-NNfLpNtsFQY25z7A4u9pp2D_vJHTNU70RDupydx4i7BrMKYw" class="img-responsive" alt="project-image1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="project-info text-center">
                                    <h5>Project Title</h5>
                                    <p class="project-info-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque minus voluptatibus obcaecati temporibus, eligendi harum in iusto quasi dicta. Sunt tempora magnam eveniet, adipisci modi quos maxime sint expedita repudiandae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
                                    <div class="project-btn">
                                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#" role="button" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-list">
                                <div class="project-image">
                                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="project-image1">
                                </div>

                                <div class="project-info text-center">
                                    <h5>Project Title</h5>
                                    <p class="project-info-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas aliquid consequuntur . </p>
                                    <div class="project-btn">
                                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#" target="_blank">visit site</a>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-list">
                                <div class="project-image">
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQAOoZwRkgQ3KDjCJ2-GRtjKDc88iUqU6mJva17ym63D2W0XwnYw" class="img-responsive" alt="project-image1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="project-info text-center">
                                    <h5>Project Title</h5>
                                    <p class="project-info-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, omnis,  </p>
                                    <div class="project-btn">
                                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#" role="button" target="_blank">Visit site</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-list">
                                <div class="project-image">
                                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="project-image1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="project-info text-center">
                                    <h5>Project Title</h5>
                                    <p class="project-info-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint similique earum labore quos quidem ab! Quibusdam fugit consectetur tenetur odit, fuga amet aliquam architecto modi sequi ea, delectus, quisquam atque.</p>
                                    <div class="project-btn">
                                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#projects" role="button">Visit site</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <body>
```

css

```
    #projects {
    background-color: #f65d52;
    /*    background-color: #2098D1;*/
}

#projects .content-title h3 {
    color: #fff;
}



.project-info {
    padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
    color: #fff;

}

.project-info h5 {

    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.project-image img {
    max-width: 480px !important;
    max-height: 480px !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.project-info-text {
    line-height: 170%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.project-btn {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-projects").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        smartSpeed: 700,
        loop: true,
        autoplayHoverPause: true
    });

});
```

Hello all,

I am having a problem with arranging divs in a carousel slider. As you can see from the above link the  position of project title in each slid is changing.So can somebody help me in fixing the width and height of each divs, so that text and images  will not overflow and in every slide all divs starts at same position instead  of going up or down.

Comment: Basically the image height is not fixed so set a fixed height if you want to give a fixed position to the title.

Comment: I set image height  using .project-info img

Comment: Added a snippet checkout that.

Answer (score 0):

Your images need a fixed height otherwise things will get pushed down or up.
if you can't set a fixed height on the images then I suggest just a fixed position of the project title and description div. Maybe make it absolute of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use a fixed height for images:

```
.project-image img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 480px;
    height: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, set fixed height to your images.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#my-projects").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    smartSpeed: 700,
    loop: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true
  });
});
```

```css
#projects {
  background-color: #f65d52;
  /*background-color: #2098D1;*/
}

#projects .content-title h3 {
  color: #fff;
}

.project-info {
  padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.project-info h5 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.project-image img {
  max-width: 480px !important;
  max-height: 480px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 340px;
}

.project-info-text {
  line-height: 170%;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.project-btn {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700,700i|Merriweather:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
  <link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="projects">
    <div class="content-box">
        <div class="content-title wow animated fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <h3>My Projects</h3>
            <div class="content-title-underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="my-projects" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                        <div class="project-list">
                            <div class="project-image">
                                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTp1-NNfLpNtsFQY25z7A4u9pp2D_vJHTNU70RDupydx4i7BrMKYw" class="img-responsive" alt="project-image1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-info text-center">
                                <h5>Project Title</h5>
                                <p class="project-info-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque minus voluptatibus obcaecati temporibus, eligendi harum in iusto quasi dicta. Sunt tempora magnam eveniet, adipisci modi quos maxime sint expedita repudiandae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
                                <div class="project-btn">
                                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#" role="button" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="project-list">
                            <div class="project-image">
                                <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="project-image1">
                            </div>

                            <div class="project-info text-center">
                                <h5>Project Title</h5>
                                <p class="project-info-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas aliquid consequuntur . </p>
                                <div class="project-btn">
                                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#" target="_blank">visit site</a>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="project-list">
                            <div class="project-image">
                                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQAOoZwRkgQ3KDjCJ2-GRtjKDc88iUqU6mJva17ym63D2W0XwnYw" class="img-responsive" alt="project-image1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-info text-center">
                                <h5>Project Title</h5>
                                <p class="project-info-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, omnis,  </p>
                                <div class="project-btn">
                                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#" role="button" target="_blank">Visit site</a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="project-list">
                            <div class="project-image">
                                <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="project-image1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-info text-center">
                                <h5>Project Title</h5>
                                <p class="project-info-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint similique earum labore quos quidem ab! Quibusdam fugit consectetur tenetur odit, fuga amet aliquam architecto modi sequi ea, delectus, quisquam atque.</p>
                                <div class="project-btn">
                                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#projects" role="button">Visit site</a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  responsiveClass for set all slide responsive.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#my-projects").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            smartSpeed: 700,
            loop: true,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            responsiveClass:true
        });

    });
```